# Any way reinstall the old iWork in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, iwork

The new iWork is an big step backward. Many transitions removed from the Keynote and so on... Is here any way to remove the new iWork and get back the old one?

Comment: If you didn't delete them, they can still be found in `/Applications/iWork '09/` (or at least they were still there when *I* updated).

Comment: @grgarside OMG - I'm blind. Thank you - you saved my life... ;) write it as answer - so i should accept it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Mac App Store updates to iWork should not have replaced the original iWork '09 apps.

The original apps should still be available under **/Applications/iWork '09** as well as if you search for them in Spotlight - just look for iWork '09 next to the name if you decide not to delete the newer versions.

If for some reason you have deleted the older versions, you can grab them from a Time Machine backup or reinstall them from a retail CD if you happened to buy them that way.