# How can I display the format bar above the document in Pages 5.0?

Tags: applications, macos, pages, iwork, word-processor

The new version of Pages has the format bar (i.e. the bar where you change the font size, typeface, alignment, spacing, etc.) on the right of the document:

[image: Pages 5.0]

I want it to be on the top of the document like in Pages 4.3 (Pages '09):

[image: Pages 4.3]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: No, you can do nothing.  At least until 5.01,  or reverting to '09.

Comment: Sorry I do not know the solution...but this arrangement is absolutely comfortable to me! In future versions Apple may please see that this is not removed.

Comment: Good question, I tried to do this, too. My research resulted in that there's no possibility to do that yet... hopefully Apple adds it in later updates...

Answer (score 4):

**This is not possible in Pages 5.0.**

If your wish for a format bar above the document outweighs any benefit from Pages 5.0, you can [continue to use iWork '09](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106647/any-way-reinstall-the-old-iwork-in-mavericks).

You can also notify Apple that you would like this feature implemented using their Pages feedback page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html

Comment: I sent Apple a feature request via the feedback page you linked. Hopefully they will ameliorate this annoying issue soon. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I don't mind having the format bar in the right during normal editing mode, but for full-screen mode it's absolutely crucial. A 'dark'/night mode for fullscreen is definitely necessary as well.